# Can you use assert to test type defintions in C++?

Tags: c++, debugging, casting, assert

Can I use [assert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cassert/assert/) to enforce type definitions. Suppose there is a variable, `double d`, how can you use `assert` to assert that d is a double? If `assert` is not applicable (which I am betting isn't), is there another option? I am specifically looking to test for implicit type casting during debugging, while benefiting from the functionality of `assert` and `#define NDEBUG`.

P.S 
Obviously I would want to use this for any type definition, just using double as an example here. The solution should be cross platform compatible and be compatible with C++03.

I like to add error checking to my class setters. For example, suppose there is a class, MyClass, with a private member variable, x:

```
void MyClass::setX(double input)
{
   // assert x is double
   x = input;
}
```

Comment: assert() is for run-time checks. For datatypes, you have a much stronger tool at your disposal - compile-time checks. Describe a specific scenario, maybe the SO collective will come up with a way to turn it into a compile error situation.

Comment: Wherever `x` was defined, make the type `double`.

Comment: @Gman, I like to add error checking to the setters for robustness.

Comment: I'm new to C++, can you tell me in what case a **double** declared parameter could be something else ? Thanks

Comment: @Niklas R: He wants to know that `x` is a double, not the parameter.

Comment: @K ah, yeah. But that should actually be declared as well ?

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: I'm not sure I follow. The value you're getting for the setter should also have the type `double`. This is all compile-time, there is no generic run-time type.

Comment: @Gman, Seva has already pointed out that this is compile-time

Comment: @NiklasR: He seems to be wanting an assert for if the _member_ is something else.  Can't imagine how that would be though.

Comment: @Elpezmuerto: Right, so then what's the question? How could it possibly be useful to assert the member variable `x` is a `double`? Just make it a `double` at its declaration.

Comment: @Gman For simple projects, making sure it is a double is relatively easy. But for large projects and for the development of custom unit tests, attempting making sure it is a `double` at declaration isn't feasible

Comment: @Elpezmuerto What else could it be? It's not like the type is unknown. Can you post some actual code where this is an issue?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's really a compile time check, so you should use static asserts for this.

Here is an example using boost's static asserts and type traits.

```
#include <boost/static_assert.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>

template<typename T>
  void some_func() {
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT( (boost::is_same<double, T>::value) );
  }

TEST(type_check) {
  some_func<double>();
}
```

I assume you mean in terms of a template anyway.

Comment: That's `BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT`, and it may need double parens since the argument has a comma.

Comment: @K-ballo You are correct sir, I have corrected.  Imagine my shame.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `==` operator defined in the `type_info` [class](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/typeinfo/type_info/) to test for a specific type definition.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main ()
{
    double a = 0;

    std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;

    assert(typeid(a)==typeid(double));
    assert(typeid(a)==typeid(int)); // FAIL
}
```

Or borrowing from another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473/how-can-i-assert-without-using-abort) using templates and try/catch:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename X, typename A>
inline void Assert(A assertion)
{
    if( !assertion ) throw X();
}

#ifdef NDEBUG
    const bool CHECK_ASSERT = false;
#else
    const bool CHECK_ASSERT = true;
#endif

struct Wrong { };

int main ()
{
    double a = 0;

    std::cout << typeid(a).name() << std::endl;

    assert(typeid(a)==typeid(double));
    Assert<Wrong>(!CHECK_ASSERT || typeid(a)==typeid(double));
    try
    {
    //assert(typeid(a)==typeid(int)); // FAIL and Abort()
        Assert<Wrong>(!CHECK_ASSERT || typeid(a)==typeid(int)); // FALL
    }
    catch (Wrong)
    {
        std::cerr <<"Exception, not an int" <<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to compare using `std::is_same` and using `decltype`. You can even use `std::static_assert` to move the check to compile time. I've seen it happen in libc++ :)

Note these are C++11 features, so you'll need to have a compiler that supports `decltype`

Comment: Should be `std::is_same`, note that a solution based on C++03 is still possible but there is not enough context information in the question to propose so. Also static_assert suits better once in C++11 world.

Comment: @K-ballo what other context is needed for C++03?

Answer (score 1):

Given the current definition of the code, a way to check at compile time whether both are of the same type is:

```
template< typename T, typename U >
void assert_same_type( T const&, U const& )
{
     int error[ sizeof( T ) ? -1 : -2 ]; // error array of negative size, dependent on T otherwise some implementations may cause an early error message even when they shouldn't
}

template< typename T >
void assert_same_type( T&, T& ){}

void MyClass::setX(double input)
{
   assert_same_type( x, input ); // If the fallback case is instantiated then a compile time error will arise of trying to declare an array of negative size.

   x = input;
}
```

Comment: @rubenvb: I'm not sure if that is actually the case, but if it is simply add an error within the fallback case. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a template function, then overload the argument type for `double` like this:

```
#include <cassert>

template<class T>
bool is_double(T) { return false; }
bool is_double(double) { return true; }

int main() {
    int i = 1;
    double d = 3.14;
    assert( is_double(d) );
    assert( is_double(i) ); // fails
}
```

That would give a run-time error. You can generate a compile time error by simply defining a function that takes a double reference:

```
void is_double(double&) { }

void MyClass::setX(double input)
{
  is_double(x); // assert x is double
  x = input;
}
```